# При разрезании тайла спрайтов появляются артефакты в спрайтах

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

Разрезаю в Unity такой тайл спрайтов. Формат png, каждый куб 128 х 128:

[image: Тайл]

И появляется неприятный артефакт, как-будто добавляется кусочек,это даже не пиксель(пиксель больше этого), а маленький кусочек, как мне кажется следующей и предыдущей текстуры. В Unity указал разрезать по размеру, указал этот размер, все разрезалось четко. Но все равно появляется артефакт на левой и правой границах:

[image: Артефакт спрайта]

У камня, что по середине, слева фиолетовая граница, а справа коричневая.

Настройки спрайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем может быть дело, 2-й день решить не могу?

Comment: оригинал можешь выложить? а то посмотрел картинку, а она 1113x225. unity какая версия?

Comment: Теперь это должен быть оригинал

Comment: Версия - 2017.1.0f3

Comment: А в старой (ну хотя бы 5.6) что показывает? при таких настройках? а то что-то слышал в 2017 опять косяки начались со значениями с плавающей точкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте! У меня была похожая проблема со спрайтами, я решил её довольно простым, как топор, но не очень красивым методом.

Добавил между разными спрайтами 2 дополнительных пикселя, например: если ваш спрайт размером 128х128, то выделял по 1 пикселю на каждую сторону типо для "резерва", итого я использовал 126х126.

[image: вроде баг SpriteEditor'a]

Comment: @1lowol1 Это называется погрешности чисел с плавающей запятой. Никто не слышал о padding? Добавьте 1-2 пикселя между текстурками в атласе и будет вам счастье, а если хотите использовать билинейность, то минимум 3 пикселя.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ нет ну смотри, вдруг ему хочется чтобы его атлас был размером 2 в степени N, и автору может хочется чтобы картинка при растягивании повторялась без искаржений, вот тогда ему придется резервировать пиксели из-за погрешности. Игра то у него пикселявая, если чо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это происходит потому, что `Filter Mode` в настройках спрайта стоит  Bilinear или Trilinear, которая отвечает за то, чтобы вблизи текстура становилась более размытой.

Возможно при разрезании, не смотря на точность границ, для размытия, так или иначе, берутся соседние пиксели и смешиваются. А, так как спрайт сам по себе цельный, то и для размытия края одного из спрайтов берутся соседние пиксели другого. И получается вот такие линии. Как вариант поставить `Filter Mode` в `Point`, который говорит, чтоб вблизи текстура становилась более пиксельной

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам сильно необходимо, чтоб вблизи все же был спрайт размыт, а не пиксельным, то пока у меня нет вариантов))

Comment: Point и стоит. Щас я добавлю скрин с полными настройками спрайта